# Type Error : Separating username from email address in Google Scripts/JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google Scripts editor in correlation with Google sheets and forms. There is a form that logs a user's email address and stores it inside the sheet.

I have used:

```
var username = sheet.getSheetValues(numRows, 2, 1, 1); //getting username
```

this returns an object "testuser@domain.com" which I then send to a function titled "removeEmail"

```
var newName = removeEmail(username);
```

...

```
function removeEmail(input) 
{
  var name =input;

  var stringLength = name.length;

  var sub = name.substring(0,stringLength-10);
  Logger.log(sub);

  //return sub;

}
```

When I created this function I had a defined email to test with, that lived inside the removeEmails function. The logger showed that it was removing the domain name perfectly. However, when I implemented this inside a bigger main function the function errors out. The message is:

**TypeError: Cannot find function substring in object testuser@domain.com. (line 24, file "removeEmail")**

I believe this is because my function removeEmails is meant for strings, as it uses the string library, but the way I grab the data from the sheet doesn't store the variable as a string. I have tried

```
username.toString();
```

before I call removeEmails, and even inside removeEmails but can't get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetvaluesstartrow-startcolumn-numrows-numcolumns), getSheetValues returns a 2-dimensional array, not a string. Try getting the username like this:

```
var values = sheet.getSheetValues(numRows, 2, 1, 1); //getting username
var username = values[0][0]; // first row, first column since we're requesting just 1 cell
```